# How to do tar on Linux at 0 level

Tags: compression, archive

How do we do tar or bsdtar on Linux set at 0 compression level, i.e. to do store only in order to unpack it directly ?
if impossible, suggest by others like zip, gzip, etc which can be piped in order to be unpacked directly

Tried:

`--level=

option not work

would one give the correct CLI code

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just make a .tar file that isn't compressed, then simply don't specify any compression options:

`tar cf whatever.tar somedirectory`

That stores the files and directories in the tar file. It can be extracted with:

`tar xf whatever.tar`